# I have a R formula for making a transition probability matrix that I want to implement in excel

Tags: r, excel, vba, excel-formula, markov-chains

I have this code to generate the transition probability matrix from a sequence repeating from 1 to 12 depicting sales.

How can I implement this code in Excel using a formula

I have no experience with VBA and I tried it in excel but failed

```
x <- e$Range
p <- matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 12, 0)
for (t in 1:(length(x) - 1)) p[x[t], x[t + 1]] <- p[x[t], x[t + 1]] + 1
for (i in 1:12) p[i, ] <- p[i, ] / sum(p[i, ])
p
```

A transition probability of each value in each cell of those 12 values.

Thank You in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following data in your excel sheet beginning at position `A1` for the `X` :

> If you want to put the two tables at differents positions modify the following variables in the macro with the new positions : `startRowNumX, startColNumX, startRowNumP, startColNumP`
>
> Note that the matix is fill with 0 and 1 because you didn't put data for an example in your post

[image]
Here a way to achieve what want you want to do with a macro :

```
Sub TransitonProbabilityMatrix()
    Dim startRowNumX, startColNumX, startRowNumP, startColNumP, sizeMatrix As Integer
    startRowNumX = 1
    startColNumX = 1
    startRowNumP = 3
    startColNumP = 1

    sizeMatrix = startColNumX
    While (Not IsEmpty(Cells(startRowNumX, sizeMatrix)))
        sizeMatrix = sizeMatrix + 1
    Wend
    sizeMatrix = sizeMatrix - startColNumX

    For i = startColNumX + 1 To startColNumX + sizeMatrix - 2
        Cells(Cells(startRowNumX, i) + startRowNumP, Cells(startRowNumX, i + 1) + startColNumP) = Cells(Cells(startRowNumX, i) + startRowNumP, Cells(startRowNumX, i + 1) + startColNumP) + 1
    Next

    For i = startRowNumP + 1 To startRowNumP + sizeMatrix - 1
        For j = startColNumP + 1 To startColNumP + sizeMatrix - 1
            Cells(i, j) = Cells(i, j) / WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, startColNumP + 1), Cells(i, startColNumP + sizeMatrix)))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This Sub first search for the size of the matrix and after apply the transition.